# Python - Looping of Functions (Reuse the output as the input a number of times)

Tags: python, ironpython

Good morning Python gurus,

Does anyone know how to use recursion to specify that a functions output is looped back to be its new input as specific number of times before then outputting the final return?

EDIT: Sorry more information below:
- IronPython
- Using Autodesk Revit
- Code excerpt

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('ProtoGeometry')
from Autodesk.DesignScript.Geometry import *

def Lmidpoint(line1):
    midpoint=Line.PointAtParameter(line1,0.5)
    return midpoint

outlist=[]
pointlist=[]

lines=IN[0]

count=len(lines)

if count > 0:
    for l in lines:
        mp=Lmidpoint(l)
        count-1
        firstline=Line.ByStartPointEndPoint(l.StartPoint,mp)
        secondline=Line.ByStartPointEndPoint(mp,l.EndPoint)
        outlist.append({firstline,secondline})
        pointlist.append(mp)
    else:
        outlist.append('Well that didnt work...')
        count-1
OUT = pointlist,outlist
```

[Code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or4NA.jpg)

Comment: I'm not clear on where you're stuck with this.  Many tutorials show how to recur for a given quantity of times, or until a more general condition occurs.  Since you link to an off-site resource, and provided no coding attempt, it's hard to know just what you want and where you have trouble.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You also need to state exactly what the problem is, what you expected, what you got, and any traceback.

Answer (score 1):

Just store the output in a variable, and pass that variable to the function again.  Do this in a loop to repeat as many times as necessary:

```
output = f(input)
for _ in range(n_repeats):
    output = f(output)
```

Comment: Where is the recursion here? (The questioner asked "how to use recursion".)

Answer (score 1):

You could always solve this iteratively, but if you're looking for a recursive approach you can just keep your base case around the number of "times" you need to run it.

If you are trying to figure out your problem on your own and just trying to understand how the process would look, then kudos. Keep it up.

```
input = 5

def recursive_f (input, n): #n being the number of times you want to run this
    if n == 0:
        return input
    output = input + 1 #some operation to get output. 
    return recursive_f (output, n - 1) 

recursive_f(input, 3) #outputs 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is considerably unclear, I just made an example of a simple recursive function:

```
def your_func(a, init, end):

    a += 1
    init += 1

    if (init < end):

        a = your_func(a, init, end)

    return a

print (your_func(2, 0, 7)) #output with these numbers will be 2 + 7 (9)
```

This function will increment its first parameter by 1 a **X** number of times, where **X = last parameter - middle parameter**.

Good part here is: if you want to, you can use a similar structure to execute any other thing on your **a** variable a number **end - init** of times. Since you are up to understand a little more about recursion in Python, I highly suggest you use your creativity a little bit and try changing **your_func** to execute different tasks.

Answer (score -1):

is a while loop what you are looking for in your project? Maybe?

```
k = 0
n = #number of repeats
input = #your input

def yourDef():
    #codehere
    return input

while k < n:
    yourDef()
```

Comment: This will re-run with the same input `n` times, rather than using the result of the previous run as the input to the next.